# 2012 logan milege 107000 milege

Tags: engine, ac, speedometer

A few weeks ago I bought a Logan from a second sale market. What should I do to keep the vehicle in good working order? The speedometer and AC sometimes do not work.

(2012 MODEL QATAR LOGAN APPRX 107000 KM RUN)

Answer (score 1):

First check what servicing has been done - also check if this record is correct...

You could give it a thorough service now to have a clear starting point and to find possible issues that you need to consider.

As for the record, is the service book in the car? If not, then a dealer may be able to get you some info based on the VIN number - but they may say that they can’t give it to you - data protection...

Answer (score 0):

While 107000 is not a huge mileage for Qatar, there would be some obvious things to check for:

1. Take the vehicle to an authorised service centre and check up on the service history.
2. If there are no service records, best to replace the fluids like engine oil, brake oil, coolant, transmission fluid, reapply grease on all points.
3. Check and replace broken/cut bushes.
4. Check suspension for sponginess.
5. Check brakes for bite, else take it to service centre to open and clean.
6. Check tire tread depth.
7. Check for rust and repair as needed.
8. Any major mechanical faults may not become obvious immediately, but check for early signs.

Speedometer may be an easy fix, check the cabling. AC would certainly need a service centre visit to check for gas or a more serious issue.